# Where can I watch Nanatsu no Taizai season 3 online?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Where can I watch *Nanatsu no Taizai* season 3 online *legally*?

Comment: Season 3 wasn't even out yet when you asked this question. First episode was 8 Oct 2019. You won't be able to watch it legally for some time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are awaiting Netflix on that. It's still unclear and they didn't announce a release date. Other than that there is no way to watch it legally afaik.